# What is this assembly code doing with the command line arguments

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, command-line-arguments

I know something is happening with the command line arguments but I don't know what. Can someone walk me through this code?

```
0x401050    <main>:         push   %ebp
0x401051    <main+1>:       mov    %esp,%ebp
0x401053    <main+3>:       sub    $0x8,%esp
0x401056    <main+6>:       and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x401059    <main+9>:       mov    $0x0,%eax
0x40105e    <main+14>:      mov    %eax,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x401061    <main+17>:      mov    0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
0x401064    <main+20>:      call   0x4013a0 <_alloca>
0x401069    <main+25>:      call   0x401430 <__main>
0x40106e    <main+30>:      mov    $0x0,%edx
0x401073    <main+35>:      add    0x8(%ebp),%edx
0x401076    <main+38>:      mov    %edx,%eax
0x401078    <main+40>:      leave  
0x401079    <main+41>:      ret
```

Comment: What system is it running on?

Comment: This is IA32 assembly running on linux

Comment: If you are leaning assembler, I would recommend starting with a simpler/cleaner processor. Arm or PowerPC, or even one of the less used older processors such as 68000. You can probably get an emulator that runs on your computer. Just checked debian has several, not tried any though.

Comment: The class I am in teaches it this way. Just like how my school starts the CS students off with C++... Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It will be quicker to, in your own time, learn Eiffel and arm first. Though scarier.

Comment: I don't know what this code is doing. It appears to be sending uninitialized data as an argument to alloca, and it doesn't do anything I can see with command line arguments, other than adjusting the stack so they aren't passed to main properly. (Of course it's calling `_main` instead of `main`, I don't know if that moves them.) It does return its first argument, whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

Without letting us know how your function is called and how the called ones are declared, we are not able to actually help you.

For Example, it's not clear whether alloca and _main are cdecl, stdcall, fastcall, etc. and how many parameters they expect, you would need to investigate them as well and see how they set up, access and clean up the stack.

As for your code, it looks kind of weird..

It calls alloca and _main without cleaning up the stack, so either they aren't cdecl or the "sub esp,8" allocates space for both calls. It then zeros eax and moves it into ebp-4, which could be a parameter to those calls. However, most of the stack is uninitialized. After calling alloca it doesn't do anything with eax, so either _main is some kind of fastcall and expects a parameter in eax or your code is plain weird. Like ughoavgfhw already said, in the end the function returns its own first parameter.

Also, you should attach a debugger and single step through your code to fully comprehend it.